# Motion in one dimension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

Here is a question which is not really hard and from my lecture PHYS101. How come does the first statement is false and second is true? Thank you.
  1. If a car is slowing down, its acceleration must be negative.
  2. A particle with constant acceleration can never stop and stay stopped.

Answer (score 2):

1. It depends on your coordinate system. If your car is driving in the negative axis direction, then you must give it positive acceleration to make it slow down.
2. Well, the definition of acceleration is *a change in velocity*. So if you stop - meaning your velocity is zero - then the presense of acceleration is changing the velocity so it's not zero anymore.

Comment: But it can stop just for a moment -for the second statement- can't it?

Comment: @user96017 Yes, it can. But it will not *stay stopped*.

Comment: Exactly. Something slows down as long as the signs of velocity and acceleration are opposing, but either one doesn't necessarily have to be positive or negative.